# EarPods Sound Works but Remote Control Doesn't?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, audio, headphones

I have a pair of EarPods that came with my iPhone 5s. They worked completely fine until the other day. When I plug them into my iPhone ***or*** my iPad, the sound worlds completely fine but the remote interface just doesn't work entirely. I have looked into the apple support communities but couldn't find anything. I have tried Cleaning the headphone jack on both devices and I have tried updating to iOS 7.0.6 **AND** iOS 7.1(I'm a developer). This issue has been bothering me and I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a hardware issue with the EarPods.

If you have an apple store nearby you can take them in and try a new set. I've gotten one set of earbuds and one set of EarPods replaced with very little trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should get a new pair of [Earpods / Headphones.](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD827LL/A/apple-earpods-with-remote-and-mic?afid=p219%7CGOUS&cid=AOS-US-KWG-PLA)

It doesn't cost much, it should be around £25.00 (UK) and $29.00 (US). I have encountered this problem a lot of times, i'd buy a new pair.